# Ошибки в функции - Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется функция:

```
    public GameObject toObjects(string object) {
    if (object == "sun") return SunObject;
    }
```

Но юнити выдает 4 ошибки:

Identifier expected - x2

Syntax error, ' , ' expected

Invalid expression term 'object'

Я задал строковый тип, непонятно почему он все равно ругается на тип, и точно так же с остальными ошибками. В чем проблема?

Comment: Что есть `SunObject` непонятно. Пишите вопросы более развернутые.

Comment: а что должно вернуться если условие не выполнилось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы выбрали неудачное имя строковому аргументу функции `object`. Попали в зарезервированное слово. Вот список [зарезервированных в сишарп](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) слов.
2. У Вас в сигнатуре метода указано что он возвращает `GameObject`, соответственно все ветви выполнения должны что-то возвращать, нужно добавить хотя бы `return null;` в конце функции.

Comment: я бы добавил что если уж хочется именно имя `object` то можно написать `@object`